# Diif ignore lines containing something

Tags: bash, diff

I have 2 two files and need to compare their with diff:

```
l1 abcdef
l2 someth1
l3 smguoljgu
l4 abcdef
```

---

```
l5 abcdef
l6 someth2
l7 smgubhmghfyf
l8 abcdef
```

How I can force diff ignore lines if it contains *abcdef*?

Comment: `diff -uN <(grep -v abcdef file1) <(grep -v abcdef file2)`?

Comment: But I need to only not change this lines, but they must display in diff output

Comment: @ComptrollerChanel, are you still looking for an answer? If you are, please, clarify why jordanm's comment is not enough.